# Couldn't find executable named rqt_graph

Tags: ros, rqt-graph, ros-indigo, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running on ubuntu 14.04 indigo. since I don't have Internet access from the computer that I am working on, therefore I cannot use `sudo apt-get ...` commands. Therefore, I used a usb to transfer all the files. I used this [link](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/indigo/distribution.yaml)  to make sure I am downloading the right for my system.

I built rqt(0.4.8) and rqt_graph(0.4.8) from the source, when I ran catkin_make, it builts successfully. However, when I try to ran `rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph`

it shows me the following:

```
/catkin_ws$ rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph

[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named rqt_graph below /home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/rqt_graph

[rosrun] Found the following, but they're either not files,

[rosrun] or not executable:

[rosrun] /home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/rqt_graph

[rosrun] /home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/rqt_graph/src/rqt_graph

[rosrun] /home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/rqt_graph/scripts/rqt_graph
```

So I went into `rqt_graph/script/rqt_graph` and made it into an executable, then I ran `rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph` again, and it gave me the following:

```
RosPluginProvider.load(rqt_graph/RosGraph) exception raised in __builtin__.__import__(rqt_graph.ros_graph, [RosGraph]): Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/rqt_gui/src/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 77, in load module = __builtin__.__import__(attributes['module_name'], fromlist=[attributes['class_from_class_type']], level=0) File "/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/rqt_graph/src/rqt_graph/ros_graph.py", line 38, in <module> from python_qt_binding.QtWidgets import QCompleter, QFileDialog, QGraphicsScene, QWidget

ImportError: No module named QtWidgets

PluginManager._load_plugin() could not load plugin "rqt_graph/RosGraph": Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/plugin_handler.py", line 99, in load self._load()

File "/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/plugin_handler_direct.py", line 54, in _load self._plugin = self._plugin_provider.load(self._instance_id.plugin_id, self._context)

File "/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)

File "/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)

File "/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/rqt_gui_py/src/rqt_gui_py/ros_py_plugin_provider.py", line 60, in load return super(RosPyPluginProvider, self).load(plugin_id, plugin_context)

File "/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/composite_plugin_provider.py", line 71, in load instance = plugin_provider.load(plugin_id, plugin_context)

File "/home/administrator/catkin_ws/src/rqt_gui/src/rqt_gui/ros_plugin_provider.py", line 83, in load raise e

ImportError: No module named QtWidgets
```

Anyone got suggestions on how I should fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/289929/couldn%27t-find-executable-named-rqt_graph/) by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2018-04-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alex_](https://answers.ros.org/users/34815/alex_/) on 2018-04-28**:
Looks like something is missing. Try running:

```
rosdep check rqt_graph
```

**Comment by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) on 2018-04-28**:
shows me: apt ros-indigo-qt-dotgraph,
so I downloaded the 0.2.32 version. Now, when I do run `rosrun rqt_`  tab tab, it actually shows me `rqt_graph`, but it still gave me the error saying can't find an executable. Then, when I made it an executable, it shows me the import error.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-04-30**:
What version of the package `ros-indigo-python-qt-binding` do you have installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up configuration multiple computer network, so that I can connect to the Husky PC1 with PC2 that has wifi. Once, the rqt_graph is downloaded on PC2, I configured the network to connect PC2 to PC1, then, from PC2, I can use rqt_graph to see all the nodes and topics.

---

Originally posted by [frodyteen](https://answers.ros.org/users/34681/frodyteen/) with karma: 62 on 2018-06-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0